# Lifetimes in generic trait implementation

Tags: rust, lifetime-scoping

I want to make a trait similar to the below structure (my particular use case is a bit more complex but this captures the issue and error I'm getting). The issue I have is which lifetimes in the last impl. I think I need to squeeze them into the trait definition but I'm not sure how. How can I sort out the lifetimes so this compiles?

[Rust playground link to code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ebfc4cbfb313bbf27b781c71625370da)

```rust
trait MyTrait<TIn> {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: Self) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(TIn) -> TOut;
}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(T) -> TOut,
    {
        f(x)
    }
}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> for &T
where
    T: Clone,
{
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: &T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(T) -> TOut,
    {
        f(x.clone())
    }
}

// This impl fails to compile:
impl<T> MyTrait<&T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> TOut,
    {
        f(&x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signature

```
impl<T> MyTrait<&T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(&T) -> TOut,
    {
    }
}
```

desugars to

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> MyTrait<&'a T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: for<'r> Fn(&'r T) -> TOut,
    {
    }
}
```

which is more general than the trait's type signature. Using

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> MyTrait<&'a T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(&'a T) -> TOut,
    {
    }
}
```

would allow this to compile but restrict the implementation to either non-termination or unsafe code.

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> MyTrait<&'a T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(&'a T) -> TOut,
    {
        //panic!(); or
        f(unsafe { &*(&x as *const T) })
    }
}
```

The unsafe version can easily cause a use after free, e.g.

```
println!("{:?}", String::f(|x: &String| x, "aa".to_string()));
```

You can instead move the bounds on `F` up ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=trait%20MyTrait%3CTIn%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20F%3A%20Fn(TIn)%20-%3E%20TOut%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(f%3A%20F%2C%20x%3A%20Self)%20-%3E%20TOut%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%20MyTrait%3CT%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%20for%20T%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20F%3A%20Fn(T)%20-%3E%20TOut%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(f%3A%20F%2C%20x%3A%20T)%20-%3E%20TOut%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(x)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%20MyTrait%3CT%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%20for%20%26T%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20T%3A%20Clone%2C%0A%20%20%20%20F%3A%20Fn(T)%20-%3E%20TOut%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(f%3A%20F%2C%20x%3A%20%26T)%20-%3E%20TOut%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(x.clone())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%20MyTrait%3C%26T%2C%20F%2C%20TOut%3E%20for%20T%0Awhere%0A%20%20%20%20F%3A%20Fn(%26T)%20-%3E%20TOut%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(f%3A%20F%2C%20x%3A%20T)%20-%3E%20TOut%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(%26x)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CString%20as%20MyTrait%3CString%2C_%2C_%3E%3E%3A%3Af(%7Cs%7Cs.len()%2C%20String%3A%3Anew())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%26String%20as%20MyTrait%3CString%2C_%2C_%3E%3E%3A%3Af(%7Cs%7Cs.len()%2C%20%26String%3A%3Anew())%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%3CString%20as%20MyTrait%3C%26String%2C_%2C_%3E%3E%3A%3Af(len%2C%20String%3A%3Anew())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20len(s%3A%26String)-%3Eusize%7B%0A%20%20%20%20s.len()%0A%7D%0A))

```
trait MyTrait<TIn, F, TOut>
where
    F: Fn(TIn) -> TOut,
{
    fn f(f: F, x: Self) -> TOut;
}

impl<T, F, TOut> MyTrait<T, F, TOut> for T
where
    F: Fn(T) -> TOut,
{
    fn f(f: F, x: T) -> TOut {
        f(x)
    }
}

impl<T, F, TOut> MyTrait<T, F, TOut> for &T
where
    T: Clone,
    F: Fn(T) -> TOut,
{
    fn f(f: F, x: &T) -> TOut {
        f(x.clone())
    }
}

impl<T, F, TOut> MyTrait<&T, F, TOut> for T
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> TOut,
{
    fn f(f: F, x: T) -> TOut {
        f(&x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your last trait does not compile because it is inherently unsafe.

Your impl is actually equivalent to:

```rust
impl<'a, T> MyTrait<&'a T> for T
```

That means, that for any type `T` and *any* lifetime `'a`, `T` implements `MyTrait<&'a T`>.  In particular, if `'a` is for example `'static`, then `T` implements `MyTrait<&'static T>`. So I could write something like this:

```rust
fn foo(x: &'static i32) -> &'static i32{
     x
}

fn main() {
    let sp: &'static i32 = {
        <i32 as MyTrait<&'static i32>>::f(foo, 42)
    };
    *sp = 0; //crash!
}
```

(I'm not sure, but I think you do not even need the `' static` here to make it crash. I cannot test it, because it does not compile!).

This case is forbidden by the type system because the trait requires:

```rust
F: Fn(TIn) -> TOut;
```

but when `TIn` is a `&T`, it is actually:

```rust
F: for <'r> Fn(&'r TIn) -> TOut;
```

that is strictly more generic than the trait.

The only way I see you can write this safely is with something like this:

```rust
impl<T: 'static> MyTrait<&'static T> for T {
    fn f<TOut, F>(f: F, x: T) -> TOut
    where
        F: Fn(&'static T) -> TOut,
    {
        f(...)
    }
}
```

But this is probably not what you want, because you cannot use `x` as argument.
Note that you even need to make `T: 'static`, to make it totally safe.

Comment: Making `'static` narrows the scope of implementation, `impl<'a, T: 'a> MyTrait<&'a T> for T {`  should work also.

Comment: @ÖmerErden: That was my first idea, but it fails with the same error message. I think that my crash code above would be allowed equally with this impl.

Comment: I presumed I'd need to change the trait as well as the impl. It seems to me that the non-compiling impl could be written as a standalone function (it seems you agree correct?) so my issue is just adjusting the trait so it covers all three usages. Perhaps I need to add a lifetime parameter to the trait?